# OS X app on Lion 10.7.2 Xcode 4.3 :: error: failed to launch <exe path> -- SBTarget is invalid

Tags: macos, osx-lion, xcode4.3, launch, lldb

The app builds with zero errors and has a single line of output after Xcode displays "Running AppName : AppName"

error: failed to launch '/tmp/HungryMeProduct/Debug/HungryMe.app/Contents/MacOS/HungryMe'
-- SBTarget is invalid

The App will not run in Xcode.

This is my first OS X app. It was doing fine until
I changed the Project Name and the name of the xcodeproj file name recently.
ProjectName, Executable Name are the same.
Deployment Target 10.6

The executable at  .../Contents/MacOS/HungryMe runs when I double click it.
Terminal window displays output.

The code signing identity remains my Developer Identity

In the schemes I see that LLDB is selected not GDB. Is this a debugger problem? What is SBTarget?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happened to me, and the issue I had was the schema Target was correct but 64 bit was selected in as the architecture instead of 32 bit, for a 32 bit only project. Once I made the switch, it started working again.

GDB had the same issue but did not report it so elegantly, instead it reported "warning: posix_spawn failed, trying execvp, error: 86". It did launch the app but could not debug it.

This can easily happen if you debug without building the project, after switching the schema, or if the schema gets switched for you due to an external change to the project file (updating or reverting your source repository using git, svn, ...)

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything metioned here. Nothing worked. It seems that I somehow imported the Info.plist twice. To fix it I selected the project and pressed the "Validate Settings" button. Afterwards it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change Target's `Architectures` in `Build Settings`